How to detect if a video is progressive or interlaced?
I'm writing some Python 3 code to analyze uploaded videos, but I'm unsure how to determine if the video is progressive or interlaced. It's probably somewhere in one of the cv2.CAP_PROP_.... properties, but I'm not sure which one. How can I detect if the video is progressive or interlaced?
cam: cv2.VideoCapture = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

if cam.isOpened():
    video_codec: str = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
    video_fps: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    video_height: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    video_width: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    total_frames: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    length: int = int(total_frames / video_fps)
    audio_samplerate: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND)
    audio_channels: int = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUDIO_TOTAL_CHANNELS)


By "analyze uploaded video's [sic]" you mean doing some computer vision? Because for what you've shown so far, using a CV library that just happens to have some convenience functionality to read video files seems like a rather poor choice of a tool. I don't see any mention of interlacing in the docs. The support of the various properties is not consistent between various backends, seems like support is mostly added by people that have a specific need for it. I'd suggest looking for some library specifically designed for manipulating or inspecting the properties of video files.

OpenCV can't do it. don't use it for this. use PyAV.

Ah yes, I never realized that until just now: OpenCV is probably overkill for my purposes. What I want to do is that users can upload video's, and that they get converted to a fixed format (height/width/fps/codecs/bitrates). No fancy image recognition needed...
